# URL in AJAX POST

Tags: jquery

I want to post these variables via AJAX:

```
       <div class="vIn" id="star">
        <div id="inner">
         <span id="1" class="disabled"></span>
         <span id="2" class="disabled"></span>
         <span id="3" class="disabled"></span>
         <span id="4" class="disabled"></span>
         <span id="5" class="disabled"></span>
         <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $_GET['cID']?>" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

With this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#inner span').click(function(){
     $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('enabled');  
     var a = $(this).attr("id");
     var cID = $("#inner input").attr("id");
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajax/rating.php",
           data: "value=+a+&cID=+cID+",
           success: function(msg){
             alert(data);
           }
         });
     });});
```

On the click event, there is no alert. Am I using the right data in $.ajax?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to alert the response from your AJAX request by any chance?

Comment: its should be : data:"value="+a+"&cID="+cID,

Comment: @Haim: No, it shouldn't be. It commonly *is*, but it shouldn't be. (See `encodeURIComponent` in your favorite JavaScript reference.) ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly recommend allowing jQuery to worry about properly encoding the string:

```
var a = $(this).attr("id");
var cID = $("#inner input").attr("id");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/rating.php",
    data: {value: a, cID: cID},   // <== change is here
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Note that I'm passing `data` into `$.ajax` as an object, not as a string. jQuery will correctly encode it for you. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details.

If you really, really want to do the encoding yourself, you have to do it explicitly:

```
data: "value=" + encodeURIComponent(a) + "&cID=" + encodeURIComponent(cID)
```

Also note that I'm alerting `msg`, not `data`, as that's what you've called the response argument to `success`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle error here...

```
       success: function(msg){
         alert(data);
       }
```

You can fix it like this...

```
       success: function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
```

There is another error here...

```
data: "value=+a+&cID=+cID+",
```

I think this should be...

```
data: "value=" + a + "&cID=" + cID,
```

If you still don't get an alert, please shout!

Comment: Or `data: {value:a, cID: cID}` which is better as it will take care of value encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Javascript expert but shouldn't it be `data: "value="+a+"&cID="+cID`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It could be `data: "value=" + encodeURIComponent(a) + "&cID=" + encodeURIComponent(cID)`, but absolutely not `data: "value="+a+"&cID="+cID`.

Answer (score 0):

`data: "value=+a+&cID=+cID+"` is trying to concatenate the values without taking care of characters with special meaning. The URL might include, for example, a `&` character.

That is what it is trying to do, what it is actually doing is setting the string literal as the value. The attempt to include variables is just making them string data.

You should have:

```
data: { "value": a, "cID": cID }
```

Comment: To be correct: `data: "value=+a+&cID=+cID+"` does not concatenate anything. It is one string.

Comment: @Felix - Note the use of the word "trying" and the entire second paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your use of $.ajax

```
data: "value=+a+&cID=+cID+",
```

'+' is the concatenation operator, what you are doing here is building the data string using the variables you set before. So you need to concat your variables with the strings "value=" etc.

eg.

```
data: "value="+a+"&cID="+cID,
```